# What semantics/grammar rule decides when to start a CompletableFuture method name with "then"?

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

Looking at the CompletableFuture composition method names, some begin with "then" and others don't.

For example:
acceptEither accepts a CompletionStage and a Consumer
applyToEither accepts a CompletionStage and a Function
thenAccept accepts a Consumer
thenApply accepts a Function

Other than that, they seem to behave the same way, returning a new CompletableFuture that executes the action when ready.

So it looks like the naming rule is that the methods beginning with "then" don't accept a CompletionStage parameter and the ones that don't begin with "then" do accept a CompletionStage parameter.

But then we have:
thenAcceptBoth, which does accept a CompletionStage parameter, breaking the rule.

Is that one just a naming disparity, or is there a reason for the exception?

More generally, can you explain the intent of prefixing the word "then" to some of the methods?

I know this does not seem like a programming question, but it most definitely would help to understand which use cases require which of the large selection of CompletableFuture methods.

Here are just the ones for "accept", in which you can see the discrepancy:

[image]

Comment: "then" means Consumer parameter will be called after this ComplatableFuture is completed. That's it..

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I guess that makes sense. acceptEither also executes after this CompletableFuture is completed, and it does not start with "then", but I guess it does not have to complete, if the other one completes first!

Comment: We will reach real enlightenment when we also understand why one method is called `whenComplete[Async]` and the other `handle[Async]`. Until then, we consider such discussions off‑topic for this side…

Comment: We will reach nirvana when we also understand who thought "obtrude" was the perfect word for forcing a value, instead of something more common, like e.g. "force", "coerce", anything that is used in every day use